# Is there a value with error library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a library that provides a 'value with error' (eg x ± y). But searching for "Haskell xyz Error" only gives error handling libraries.

I would expect that such a library would provide common math operations (`Num`, `Floating`) where appropriate. The use case would be to get a error estimate from a calculation based on noisy sensor readings.

### Update

I did some research and the term "[propagation of uncertainty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)" came up. I found `uncertainly-haskell` which I'll try out soon. Are there other packages like this?

Comment: How do you compare such numbers for equality?

Comment: Probably like every floating point number: with an epsilon.

Comment: As for `uncertainly-haskell`, which I'm the author of, I'm afraid that is nowhere near usable yet. As so often in Haskell, I wanted to make it as general and mathematically appealling as possible, and so I first clashed with suitable `Applicative` / `Category` instances, then with the right domain spaces to work in. I have since been doing some research on how to implement _manifolds_ as Haskell types, but not to much avail yet. (Of course, I'm happy if you try to use it and perhaps develop so it actually works, if only in simpler spaces... but there's lots of work to be done to get there.)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [intervals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intervals) package.

Comment: Hmm ... this is probably what I am searching for. Although it is not immediately obvious (at least to me) that `I 0 1` equals `0 ± 0.5`.

Comment: Hmm ... I had a better look at the package and did some research on the topic. Please see the updated question again.

Answer (score 2):

The [Data.Eq.Approximate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/approximate-equality-1.1) module seems to be a fit for getting approximate equality.

> ## Data.Eq.Approximate
>
> Contents
>   Type wrappers
>   Classes for tolerance type annotations
>   Absolute tolerance
>   Relative tolerance
>   Zero tolerance
>   Tolerance annotations using Digits
>   The purpose of this module is to provide newtype wrapper that allows one to effectively override the equality operator of a value so that it > is approximate rather than exact. For example, the type
>
> type ApproximateDouble = AbsolutelyApproximateValue (Digits Five) Double
>   defines an alias for a wrapper containing Doubles such that two doubles are equal if they are equal to within five decimals of accuracy; for > example, we have that
>
> 1 == (1+10^^(-6) :: ApproximateDouble)
>   evaluates to True. Note that we did not need to wrap the value 1+10^^(-6) since AbsolutelyApproximateValue is an instance of Num. For > convenience, Num as well as many other of the numerical classes such as Real and Floating have all been derived for the wrappers defined in > this package so that one can conveniently use the wrapped values in the same way as one would use the values themselves.
>
> Two kinds of wrappers are provided by this package.

Answer (score 0):

The [`uncertain`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uncertain#readme) package seems to provide what you are looking for:

Some highlights from the readme:

> Provides tools to manipulate numbers with inherent
>   experimental/measurement uncertainty, and propagates them through
>   functions based on principles from statistics.

> #### Manipulate with error propagation
>
> ```
> ghci> let x = 1.52 +/- 0.07
> ghci> let y = 781.4 +/- 0.3
> ghci> let z = 1.53e-1 `withPrecision` 3
>
> ghci> cosh x
> 2.4 +/- 0.2
>
> ghci> exp x / z * sin (y ** z)
> 10.9 +/- 0.9
>
> ghci> pi + 3 * logBase x y
> 52 +/- 5
> ```

> #### Create numbers
>
> ```
> ghci> 1.52 +/- 0.07
> 1.52 +/- 7.0e-2
>
> ghci> fromSamples [12.5, 12.7, 12.6, 12.6, 12.5]
> 12.58 +/- 7.0e-2
> ```

> ### Comparisons
>
> Note that this is very different from other libraries with similar
>   data types (like from [intervals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/intervals) and [rounding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rounding)); these do not
>   attempt to maintain intervals or simply digit precisions; they instead
>   are intended to model actual experimental and measurement data with
>   their uncertainties, and apply functions to the data with the
>   uncertainties and properly propagating the errors with sound
>   statistical principles.
>
> For a clear example, take
>
> ```
> > (52 +/- 6) + (39 +/- 4)
> 91.0 +/- 7.0
> ```
>
> In a library like [intervals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/intervals), this would result in `91 +/- 10`
>   (that is, a lower bound of 46 + 35 and an upper bound of 58 + 43). 
>   However, with experimental data, errors in two independent samples
>   tend to "cancel out", and result in an overall aggregate uncertainty
>   in the sum of approximately 7.